# How to send an array of maps and iterate over it using gin-templating

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling, go-templates, go-gin

Following is the snippet of a working code. I am using gin templating engine.

```
c.HTML(200, "index", gin.H{
            "title":    "Welcome",
            "students": map[int]map[string]string{1: {"PID": "1", "Name": "myName"}},})
```

And in index template I have:

```
 <TABLE class= "myTable" >
        <tr class="headingTr">
            <td>Name</td>
        </tr>
        {{range $student := .students}}
        <td>{{$student.Name}}</td>                    
        {{end}}
 </TABLE>
```

As you can see I have hard-coded the value of `students` on the headers (the map). I want to have this data from a rest API that I have built. the response of my rest API is an array:

```
 [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mary"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "John"
  }
]
```

I can unmarshal this JSON response into `map[string]string` instead of `map[int]map[string]string`. How can pass this unmarhsaled body in parameter value for students and then iterate over this array the index template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With a struct

What you have is a JSON array, unmarshal it into a Go slice. Recommended to create a `Student` struct to model your students to have a clean and conscious Go code.

And in the template the `{{range}}` action sets the dot `.` to the current element, you can refer to it inside the `{{range}}` body simply as the dot `.`, so the student name will be `.Name`.

Working code (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/b_oP7d93BV)):

```
func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(templ))
    var students []Student
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsondata), &students); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    params := map[string]interface{}{"Students": students}
    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, params); err != nil {
        panic(nil)
    }
}

const jsondata = `[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mary"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "John"
  }
]`

const templ = `<TABLE class= "myTable" >
        <tr class="headingTr">
            <td>Name</td>
        </tr>
        {{range .Students}}
        <td>{{.Name}}</td>                    
        {{end}}
 </TABLE>`
```

Output:

```
<TABLE class= "myTable" >
        <tr class="headingTr">
            <td>Name</td>
        </tr>

        <td>Mary</td>                    

        <td>John</td>                    

 </TABLE>
```

### With a map

If you don't want to create and use a `Student` struct, you can still do it with a simple map whose type is `map[string]interface{}` which can represent any JSON object, but know that in this case you have to refer to students' names as `.name` as that is how it appears in the JSON text, and so lowercased `"name"` key will be used in the unmarshaled Go map:

```
func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(templ))
    var students []map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsondata), &students); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    params := map[string]interface{}{"Students": students}
    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, params); err != nil {
        panic(nil)
    }
}

const templ = `<TABLE class= "myTable" >
        <tr class="headingTr">
            <td>Name</td>
        </tr>
        {{range .Students}}
        <td>{{.name}}</td>                    
        {{end}}
 </TABLE>`
```

Output is the same. Try this variant on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Z5yChyWI3e).